# Assign Kentico smart search index to CMSSearchResults control datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

**EDIT:** Maybe this will make my question more clear.  I want to do this, but with a CMSSearchResults control and a search index as the DataSource:

```
// code-in-front
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" ruant="server"></asp:Repeater>

// code behind
private void BindDataToRepeater()
{
    DataSet ds = PopulateDataSet();

    repStuff.DataSource = ds;
    repStuff.DataBind();
}
```

---

I'm trying to implement a custom search user control.  I have a `<cms:CMSSearchResults>` control in my ascx file like so:

```
<cms:CMSSearchResults ID="ssIssues" runat="server"></cms:CMSSearchResults>
```

And in my code behind I'm working on a method that should retrieve a typical custom table smart search index and use the data within the index as the data source for `ssIssues`.  Here's what I have so far that should give you a rough idea of what I'm wanting to do:

```
private void BindSearchResults()
{
    SearchIndexInfo si = SearchIndexInfoProvider.GetSearchIndexInfo(int searchIndexId);

    // some tweaking to convert si to dataset

    ssIssues.DataSource = si;
    ssIssues.DataBind();
}
```

However, right off the bat I'm running into some issues and can't seem to find any documentation that will help me understand this part of the search api.

I'm getting the correct `SearchIndexInfo` object, but it doesn't seem to have any way of accessing the actual data in the index.  Now, my understanding of how search indexes work in kentico is that they analyze a set of data in SQL Server and convert that data into a b-tree that's stored in the filesystem of the webserver in the Kentico project.

So, I was expecting a method in `SearchIndexInfo` that did something along the lines of parsing that index file and returning the b-tree as a `LinkedList<t>` or a method that could be provided some arguments to sort the linked list into a `DataSet` - or at least did the parsing and allowed me to do the converting.  No such luck though, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

How exactly should I be binding a search index `DataSet` to the `CMSSearchResults` control?

Comment: What part of your control is custom or is something that the OOTB control cannot do?  What is your desired result other than writing custom code?

Comment: I'm using OOTB Kentico controls - those won't be custom, and I'm working strictly with the default Kentico API (v7).  The user control I'm developing will use the default Kentico search controls - search results, search filter, search dialog - but will be populating their properties dynamically and triggering events based on some complex logic.  I'm setting this up in a user control because it will be much easier to manage all the moving pieces in Visual Studio than having to work through the Kentico UI.  As stated, I'm just trying bind data from a search index to a search results control.

Comment: So technically speaking, yes they are custom.  Although you're using OOTB controls, you're creating your own control with your own logic to replicate the same thing which has already been coded which you can use from within the UI.  So back to my other question(s), what is your desired outcome?  Do you want a textbox for the user to enter text into?  Do you want some filtering?  Do you want a custom view of the list?

Comment: Yes, there are webparts that accomplish pieces of what I'm needing to do, but not all.  However, those webparts use controls within Kentico's assemblies .  Yes I'm making a custom control, but I'm using Kentico's controls that those webparts also use.  I'm just plugging data into them and triggering different views based on a lot of parameters that I neither want to write out nor do you need to know.  This would be too cumbersome to maintain within the UI.  My question was very specific:  "How exactly should I be binding a search index DataSet to the CMSSearchResults control?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've already started with customization, I'd suggest you to build you own control from scratch, but utilize Kentico search API to get data from search index. Following is a code snippet from Kentico API Examples:

```
private bool SearchText()
{
    // Get the search index
    SearchIndexInfo index = SearchIndexInfoProvider.GetSearchIndexInfo("MyNewIndex");

    if (index != null)
    {
        // Prepare parameters
        SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters()
        {
            SearchFor = "home",
            SearchSort = SearchHelper.GetSort("##SCORE##"),
            Path = "/%",
            ClassNames = "",
            CurrentCulture = "EN-US",
            DefaultCulture = CultureHelper.DefaultCulture.IetfLanguageTag,
            CombineWithDefaultCulture = false,
            CheckPermissions = false,
            SearchInAttachments = false,
            User = (UserInfo)CMSContext.CurrentUser,
            SearchIndexes = index.IndexName,
            StartingPosition = 0,
            DisplayResults = 100,
            NumberOfProcessedResults = 100,
            NumberOfResults = 0,
            AttachmentWhere = String.Empty,
            AttachmentOrderBy = String.Empty,
        };

        // Search
        DataSet results = SearchHelper.Search(parameters);

        // If found at least one item
        if (parameters.NumberOfResults > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  The methods for actually performing a search are part of the SearchHelper class.  I just need the name of the index (plus other params) to perform a query against.  That makes perfect sense.  Thank you, Roman.